# Finding roots of polynomial $X^2 - X + 19$ in $\mathbb Z/61 \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots, quadratics

For $p = 61$.

I was given the roots of $X^2 + 3$ in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$, which are $\pm 27 + p\mathbb Z$.

I then must find the roots of $X^2 - X + 19$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, which I have found without using the previous information.

However, I am supposed to use the given information to find the roots of $X^2 - X + 19$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, to which, I have no clue how to move forward.

Comment: The third paragraph of OP contradicts the second paragraph.

Comment: ah I meant that I have solved it without the given information, but I was just informed that I needed to include that information. I apologize for that

Comment: without the given information it is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794309/finding-roots-of-a-polynomial-using-quadratic-reciprocity)

Comment: The discriminant of $x^2-x+19$ is $-75=5^2(-3)$. You know the square root of $-3$, so...

Comment: How would I then move forward to finding the roots? Would I use the square root of -3 and 5^2 as the discriminant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete the square.

$X^2-X+19\equiv0\bmod61\iff 4X^2-4X+76\equiv0\bmod61$

$\iff (2X-1)^2\equiv-75=-3\times 5^2 \bmod61$

$\iff 2X-1\equiv\pm27\times5\bmod61$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes! thank you!